# Best way to allow other components to change table's focused row?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have `displayProjectTable` that gets state from reducer `projectData` and populates itself.

Currently `displayProjectTable` has a local state that stores `focusedRowID`. My problem is that I want other components to have the ability to modify the `focusedRowID` and it's content.

Some examples:
-A component tells `displayProjectTable` to add 1 to `focusedRowID` (ie. focus on the next row)
-A component tells `displayProjectTable` to set value of row at `focusedRowID` to "test". Because `displayProjectTable` gets its state from `projectData`, that reducer's state will have to be changed at the `focusedRowID` index.

A possible solution is to store `focusedRowID` inside of the `projectData.js` reducer. However, this seems like a bad solution to me. The `projectData` reducer is responsible for fetching, storing, and saving `projectData`. Would it really make sense to store a `focusedRowID` when `projectData` shouldn't even know what a row is?